# Mock gps with joystick ios

Tags: mocking, gps, location

How can you fake and control location on iOS

App Store and web search like for Pokémon go so you can play without leaving the house and control with a joystick App Store and web search like for Pokémon go so you can play without leaving the house and control with a joystick